# On the chain rule of matrix differential

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For $a \in \mathbb{R}^n, X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$, I know that $\frac{\partial a^\top X b}{\partial X} = a b^\top$.

But when each element of $X$ is a function of time $t$, I am wondering how to use chain rule to derive $\frac{\partial a^\top X^2(t) b}{\partial t}$ if $\frac{\partial X(t)}{\partial t}$ is known?

Answer (score 1):

It would work as follows:
$$
\frac{\partial a^{T} X^2(t) b}{dt} = 
a^{T} \frac{\partial X (t)}{dt} X b +
a^{T} X \frac{\partial X (t)}{dt} b 
$$
Just act on the first matrix by differential, and then on the second

Answer (score 0):

spiridon_the_sun_rotator already gave the answer.

Here's an alternative answer which uses the chain rule. Actually, the main point of my argument is the computation $\frac{d}{dX}(a^TX^2b)$ via directional derivative.

Define $c(t) = X(t)$ and $f(X) = a^TX^2b$, then we see that $(f\circ c)(t) = a^TX(t)^2b$.

By the Chain Rule, we see that
\begin{align}
D(f\circ c) = D(f)(Dc(t)) = D(f)(X'(t)).
\end{align}
So, it suffices to compute $Df$. Observe, the directional derivative of $f$ is given by
\begin{align}
Df(A) = \frac{d}{dt}f(X+tA)\bigg|_{t=0} = \frac{d}{dt}a^T(X+tA)^2b\bigg|_{t=0} = a^T(XA+AX)b.
\end{align}
Hence it follows
\begin{align}
Df(A)=  a^TXAb + a^TAXb = \operatorname{tr}(ba^TXA)+\operatorname{tr}(Xba^TA).
\end{align}
In short, we see that $Df(\cdot) = \operatorname{tr}((ba^TX+Xba^T)\cdot )$.

Fitting everything together, we get
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}(a^TX(t)^2b) = \operatorname{tr}((ba^TX+Xba^T)X'(t) ) = a^TXX'b+a^TX'Xb. 
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems that any matrix differential can be derived by using this trace trick.